# adding code from jquery script to another jquery script

Tags: jquery

I am using [TipTip](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin) (jQuery-Plugin for Infoboxes on hover) 
and [Bootstrap FileStyle](http://markusslima.github.io/bootstrap-filestyle/) (jQuery plugin to modify fileinputs)

now i want to add a TipTip for FileStyle :D

i tried it with this code:

```
$(":file").filestyle({
    buttonText: 'Choose File',
    classInput: "large",
    icon: false
});

$('.bootstrap-filestyle label span').addClass('tip-right');     // for TipTip
$('.bootstrap-filestyle label span').prop("title","Only JPG");      // for TipTip
```

my code looks now like i want! the class and the title were added! but TipTip doesn't fire on hover (got no errors in console).

any ideas whats wrong here? and i don't mean myself :D

Answer (score 0):

try to use jQuery.noConfilct()  function it's  if  the other lib using $ sign to define it's object